# Python finding the area of the intersection of two rectangles

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to use shapely to find the intersection of two rectangles given two points which I can then expand to four points and so I currently have something like this...

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

polygon = Polygon([(-3, 2), (1, 2), (-3, -2), (1, -2)])
other_polygon = Polygon([(2, 1), (-1, 1), (2, 4), (-1, 4)])

if polygon.overlaps(other_polygon):
  print( polygon.intersection(other_polygon).area )
else:
  print(0)
```

those points are normally stored as variables but to reduce how much code I was throwing up here I cut out all that logic and excess information but in essence this is what is getting passed through. But it keeps throwing back this error and I cant make sense of what shapely is angry about...

```
TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Self-intersection at or near point -1 0 at -1 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 66, in <module>
    print( polygon.intersection(other_polygon).area )
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapely/geometry/base.py", line 676, in intersection
    return geom_factory(self.impl['intersection'](self, other))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapely/topology.py", line 70, in __call__
    self._check_topology(err, this, other)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapely/topology.py", line 35, in _check_topology
    raise TopologicalError(
shapely.errors.TopologicalError: The operation 'GEOSIntersection_r' could not be performed. Likely cause is invalidity of the geometry <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x7f49b40b2ee0>
```

and if you really wanna see some really ugly code now that I have been trying to get it to work for a while now...

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = int(x)
        self.y = int(y)

ax1,ay1,ax2,ay2, = input().split()
bx1,by1,bx2,by2 = input().split()

ATL = Point(ax2, ay2)
ATR = Point(ax1, ay2)
ABL = Point(ax2, ay1)
ABR = Point(ax1, ay1)
if ax1 < ax2:
  if ay1 > ay2:
    ATL = Point(ax1, ay1)
    ATR = Point(ax2, ay1)
    ABL = Point(ax1, ay2)
    ABR = Point(ax2, ay2)
  else:
    ATL = Point(ax1, ay2)
    ATR = Point(ax2, ay2)
    ABL = Point(ax1, ay1)
    ABR = Point(ax2, ay1)
else:
  if ay1 > ay2:
    ATL = Point(ax2, ay1)
    ATR = Point(ax1, ay1)
    ABL = Point(ax2, ay2)
    ABR = Point(ax1, ay2)

BTL = Point(bx2, by2)
BTR = Point(bx1, by2)
BBL = Point(bx2, by1)
BBR = Point(bx1, by1)
if bx1 < bx2:
  if by1 > by2:
    BTL = Point(bx1, by1)
    BTR = Point(bx2, by1)
    BBL = Point(bx1, by2)
    BBR = Point(bx2, by2)
  else:
    BTL = Point(bx1, by2)
    BTR = Point(bx2, by2)
    BBL = Point(bx1, by1)
    BBR = Point(bx2, by1)
else:
  if by1 > by2:
    BTL = Point(bx2, by1)
    BTR = Point(bx1, by1)
    BBL = Point(bx2, by2)
    BBR = Point(bx1, by2)

# polygon = Polygon([(ATL.x, ATL.y), (ATR.x, ATR.y), (ABL.x, ABL.y), (ABR.x, ABR.y)])
# other_polygon = Polygon([(BTL.x, BTL.y), (BTR.x, BTR.y), (BBL.x, BBL.y), (BBR.x, BBR.y)])

# -3 2 1 -2
# 2 1 -1 4


from shapely.geometry import Polygon

polygon = Polygon([(-3, 2), (1, 2), (-3, -2), (1, -2)])
other_polygon = Polygon([(2, 1), (-1, 1), (2, 4), (-1, 4)])

if polygon.overlaps(other_polygon):
  print( polygon.intersection(other_polygon).area )
else:
  print(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your polygons are invalid:

```py
>>> polygon.is_valid
False
>>> other_polygon.is_valid
False
```

This is because you didn't specify the vertices in the right order. If you trace them yourself, you will see a zigzag pattern. To fix this, switch the last two vertices:

```py
>>> polygon = Polygon([(-3, 2), (1, 2), (1, -2), (-3, -2)])
>>> polygon.is_valid
True
>>> other_polygon = Polygon([(2, 1), (-1, 1), (-1, 4), (2, 4)])
>>> other_polygon.is_valid
True
```

and your intersection calculation will also work:

```py
>>> polygon.overlaps(other_polygon)
True
>>> polygon.intersection(other_polygon).area
2.0
```